# Getting specific data from MySQL and echo it with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am new here and just registered to ask a question. First of all i am newbie to PHP,so i have not tons of experience in it. My problem is the following:

I got two tables in my database. The first one is called products. The products table gives new products in my shop an unique ID. The second one is the products_to_categories table, in this table the products_id gets an cateogries_id so you know which product belongs to which category.

Now i need to echo the images (products_images in products-table) from the last 4 products (there is also a products_date_added attribute) of a category. All i managed to do until now is to echo the links of the images from the product tables:

```
mysql_select_db('example2');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval))
{
    echo "Product Image : {$row['products_image']}  <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);

?>    
</body>
```

could someone help me to do that? 
thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the output of `{$row['products_image']}`

Comment: Product Image : product-1.jpg 
--------------------------------
Product Image : product-2.jpg 
--------------------------------

Comment: And so ? What is your problem ?

Comment: @MaggsWeb OP said it was the "links of the images"

Comment: Why don't you add a `category_id` field to the `products` table? That makes your queries way easier.

Comment: well the first problem is it shows me the images as links, i need the images itself, and the second thing is to get the last 4 images of one specific category.  it´s a shopsystem that made all these tables, i am not sure if it would be so easy adding the categories_id to the products table

Comment: I allready answer to your question to have the last 4 results. Don't duplicate your questions plz (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914840/get-4-elements-out-of-mysql/31914898#31914898) and don't duplicate accounts.

Comment: Your code doesn't fetch what you describe. You should probably use a (LEFT) JOIN in SQL to match the `category_id` to the products. Than you can easily filter on the category id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap img tags (html) around the links you echo, so

```
echo "Product Image : {$row['products_image']}  <br> ".
```

becomes

```
echo "Product Image : <img src=\"{$row['products_image']}\"/>  <br> ".
```

and as for the results, you can limit the search by using **LIMIT** 4 and **ORDER BY** to sort it by the date **products_date_added**

Comment: i wrapped the img tag around and it told me: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ',' or ';' in D:\www\htdocs\admin\test.php on line 27

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to escape the quotes.

Comment: This seems to work so far, thank you. just one more question. How do i tell PHP to wrap the -->"<---around {$row['products_image']}\

Comment: You can escape quotes using this --> \ <--. If you open with a ", you have to close with it also, if you plan on using one inside the string itself then you'll need to escape it first. There are many ways to go about it.

Comment: ok i got everything to work now, it´s limited to four and sorted by the date. Thanks so far! Now the only missing thing is the connection to the other table to only show a specific category.